# Multi Window Python UI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I recently took on the task of learning Python and over the past 6 weeks I think I have made good strides. Though, it has been difficult to overcome some hurdles.

Can someone please point me in the direction I need to go?
The purpose is to grab a number from an excel spreadsheet

```py
source = "C:\\Users\\numbers.xlsx"
destination = "C:\\Users\\Yubay\\numbers.xlsx"
shutil.copy(source, destination)
```

```py
global df 
global number
```

declaring global - since I used df and number in multiple functions, I think this is what I should do?

```py
def data_frame(df):
     df = pd.read_excel(destination)
     df['Number'] = df['Number'].astype(str).str.lstrip('0')


def func(event=None):
    number_value = number_entry.get()
    process_number(number_value)


def process_number(number_value):
    df = pd.read_excel(destination)
    df['Number'] = df['Number'].astype(str).str.lstrip('0')
    number = number_value
    if number:
        result = df.loc[df['Number'] == number]
        if not result.empty:
            action = result['Action'].values[0]
            print(f"Action: {action}")
            root.destroy()
        else:
            print("No actions found.")
    else:
        print("No number entered.")


root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("420x320")
root.title("Number Test")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.bind('<Return>', func)
list_number = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Please enter a number:", font=("Roboto", 20))
list_number.pack()
number_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, placeholder_text="Enter Number", font=("calibri", 14), width=200,
                                        fg_color="white")
number_entry.pack()
ttk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=func).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Now, somewhere between the root and main window I think I am having issues:

The error is:

```py
invalid command name "1839935667904update"
    while executing
"1839935667904update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "1839928928320check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"1839928928320check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
```

I did try and place `main_window()` within the process_number function after root is terminated. no luck.
def main_window was also moved toward the top prior to def process_number

I have also swapped `root.destroy()` with `customtkinter.CTk.quit()`.

Now, I do receive a different error, which is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yubay\PycharmProjects\numberReport\numbertest.py", line 648, in <module>
    main_window.mainloop()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mainloop'
```

The next window to be opened is:

```py
def main_window():
    window = customtkinter.CTk()
    # window.after(4000, data_frame)
    window.title("Number Test")
    window.geometry("520x680")
    window.resizable(False, False)
    today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    main_frame = CTkFrame(window)
    main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    my_canvas = CTkCanvas(main_frame)
    my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    my_scrollbar = CTkScrollbar(main_frame, command=my_canvas.yview)
    my_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    frame = CTkFrame(my_canvas)
    my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="nw")
    frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def on_frame_configure(my_canvas):
        my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))
        frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: on_frame_configure(my_canvas))
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vert_sb.set)
        vert_sb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        my_canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=frame, anchor="nw")


    vert_sb = CTkScrollbar(window, orientation="vertical", command=my_canvas.yview)


main_window()
```

The next window is basically just going to auto-populate every entry field associated with the number in column A aka 'Number' and columns B-F would have information that would be added into their corresponding entry field.

Principle is to have a window open up to enter a number and if that number is found it will close the window and open up a new one, as if I were continuing more details regarding that number.  So, I would save the number and call it in the future.

I also found getting a functioning scroll bar to be a huge pain. (if you have better suggestions than having to triple layer, I'm all ears.

Where should I look to resolve my issue?

Comment: The `invalid command name` part is safe to ignore, and not a real error - more of a warning. The error with the `main_window.mainloop()`, is telling you that `main_window` is not a `ctk` window object, instead it's a function. You probably define `main_window` as a window and then as a function which causes the error.